# Explicit expression of Padé–Hermite approximant of type I

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, power-series

It is well known that the Padé approximants $(P,Q)$ of an analytic function in the neighborhood of $0$ can be expressed as a quotient of Hankel determinants built on the  coefficients of the function $f$.

Does  there exist such a formula for a general Padé–Hermite type I approximant that is
$P_1f_1+\dotsb+P_nf_n=\mathcal O(z^{\rho})$
where the $f_i$ are analytic in the neighborhood of $0$. Can one give a "explicit" formula for the $P_i$?

Answer (score 0):

Can be found in Approximants de Padé-Hermite (première partie:théorie) [Della Dora, J. Di Crescenzo]  book: Numerische Mathematik (1984), Springer